# Custom label on shipping service in Checkout

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I am grouping multiple products of an order and ask buyer to select a shipping service for each group.(because they get dispatched from different locations and have different delivery options)

This works ok, I can see the summarised shipping services at the checkout review (e.g. a line for each service with a value of service cost times number of groups this has been selected for).

However I cannot manage to label each shipping line item properly so that we would know what shipping was selected for which group/product. I am using the flat rate module. The label on checkout review pane is still the title of the shipping service as defined in the backend.

After modifying the line_item_label, the line item shipping service display_title or title, I still get the name of the shipping service instead of my custom text.

I am not using Rules because my logic is too complex. dpm-ing the line items shows the altered title.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Could you expand on which module or method you use to group the shipping services per product group?

Comment: I did this programmatically. I have different groups of sellers and in each one the group or the individual seller does the fulfilment. Because of that I end up with various fulfilment centres in the shipping page and they you can select a service for each.

Answer (score 1):

According to `commerce_shipping.api.php` you could use the following hook:

> If you need to add
>    additional information for your shipping services or alter the apperance of
>    other modules' shipping services, you can use this hook to do so with the
>    order object available.

```
function hook_commerce_shipping_service_rate_options_alter(&$options, $order, &$form_state) {
  // No example.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the module https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_payment_alter.
In that case no custom development would be required.